# Debounce jquery scroll events

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, debouncing

I just have a general question about debouncing. I have three menus at different positions on the page that when they reach a position 85px from the top of the window on scroll they become fixed. They are layered to overlap as they reach the top. I currently have a function for each and am looking to optimise as much as possible. My reading indicates the .offset.top calculation is quite taxing.

My question is: Am I overthinking it and is it necessary to debounce in this case? If my interpretation is right the three offset calculations are performed constantly on scroll. Can anyone suggest an optimisation or alterntively explain why it is not neccesary.

Thank you.

```
$(function(){
    // Check the initial Position of the fixed_nav_container
    var stickyHeaderTop0 = $('.fixed_heading_shop').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop0-85) {
                    $('.fixed_heading_shop').css({position: 'fixed', top: '85px'});  
                    $('.ghost_div0').css({display: 'block'});
            } else {
                    $('.fixed_heading_shop').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
                    $('.ghost_div0').css({display: 'none'});
            }   

    });

  }); 


$(function(){
    // Check the initial Position of the fixed_nav_container
    var stickyHeaderTop1 = $('.fixed_heading_pricetable').offset().top;

     $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop1-85 ) {
                    $('.fixed_heading_pricetable').css({position: 'fixed', top: '85px'});  
                    $('.ghost_div1').css({display: 'block'});       
            } else {
                    $('.fixed_heading_pricetable').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
                    $('.ghost_div1').css({display: 'none'});    
            }
         });

}); 



$(function(){
    // Check the initial Position of the fixed_nav_container
    var stickyHeaderTop2 = $('.fixed_heading_layout').offset().top;
     $(window).scroll(function(){    
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop2-85) {
                    $('.fixed_heading_layout').css({position: 'fixed', top: '85px'});  
                    $('.ghost_div2').css({display: 'block'});
            } else {
                    $('.fixed_heading_layout').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
                    $('.ghost_div2').css({display: 'none'});
            }
          });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case, I think it's really a matter of preference. Take a look at how the site responds in your given situation, and make adjustments if you feel the user experience is negatively affected. I tend to throttle/debounce scroll events.

There are a few things you can do to speed up your scroll handlers (slightly). If you can use id's, for example, as in jQuery's guide to [optimizing selectors](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/), e.g. `$('#myElement')` is fast because it uses `document.getElementById`.

More minor adjustments if you're worried about performance: Don't make any calls to adjust css if no call is needed. i.e. if nothing changed since the last time the scroll handler was fired. (See `isFixed` boolean)

```
$(function(){
  var OFFSET = 85;
  var WAIT = 10;

  // Check the initial Position of the fixed_nav_container
  var stickyHeaderTop0 = $('.fixed_heading_shop').offset().top;
  var isFixed = false; // assuming that's the right default value

  $(window).scroll(_.throttle(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop0 - OFFSET) {
      if(!isFixed) {
        $('#fixed_heading_shop').css({position: 'fixed', top: OFFSET+'px'});
        $('#ghost_div0').css({display: 'block'});
        isFixed = true;
      }
    }
    else {
      if(isFixed) {
        $('#fixed_heading_shop').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
        $('#ghost_div0').css({display: 'none'});
        isFixed = false;
      }
    }
  }, WAIT));
});
```

The only repeated call is `$(window).scrollTop()` and if you can combine all your scroll handlers (3?) then you would only need to make that call once per [throttled] scroll event.

Comment: I also wouldn't rule out setting a css class on a parent element, something like `$('body').toggleClass('fixed-menus', fixedBool);` add have your rules in a stylesheet.

Comment: Changing to id's has made a noticable difference in chrome. Going to look at Developer107's suggestion for optimisation then try your debounce method on top.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for combining the scroll handlers? Combining the approaches has proven a bit of a problem for me.

Comment: Got the undeline library and throttling working. I've marked you correct because technically your answer related the most to my question. Still interested in combining the handlers though if you have any suggestions?

Comment: @JPB Here's an [example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srwhu534/1/), not sure if it will fit your case exactly, but hopefully points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put in, its perfect for my needs and I'm amazed. Im' going through it bit by bit. This lightning fast fixed div on scroll script will come in handy so many times. Thank you very much, I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Without making any changes in HTML mark up, you can optimize your code a little:

```
$(function(){
// Check the initial Position of the fixed_nav_container
 var stickyHeaderTop0 = $('.fixed_heading_shop').offset().top;
 var stickyHeaderTop1 = $('.fixed_heading_pricetable').offset().top;
 var stickyHeaderTop2 = $('.fixed_heading_layout').offset().top;
 $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop0-85) {
                $('.fixed_heading_shop').css({position: 'fixed', top: '85px'});  
                $('.ghost_div0').css({display: 'block'});
        } else {
                $('.fixed_heading_shop').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
                $('.ghost_div0').css({display: 'none'});
        }
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop1-85 ) {
                $('.fixed_heading_pricetable').css({position: 'fixed', top: '85px'});  
                $('.ghost_div1').css({display: 'block'});       
        } else {
                $('.fixed_heading_pricetable').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
                $('.ghost_div1').css({display: 'none'});    
        }
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop2-85) {
                $('.fixed_heading_layout').css({position: 'fixed', top: '85px'});  
                $('.ghost_div2').css({display: 'block'});
        } else {
                $('.fixed_heading_layout').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
                $('.ghost_div2').css({display: 'none'});
        }
 });
});
```

And if you give a common class to the three elements for which the if..else functionality is same, then it will be more optimized.
I am adding a class 'common' here in JS, you can add it in html itself.

```
$(function(){
// add common class to elements
 $('.fixed_heading_shop, .fixed_heading_pricetable, .fixed_heading_layout').addClass('common');
 var elemArr = [];
 // Check the initial Position of the fixed_nav_container
 $('.common').each(function(index){
        elemArr.push($(this).offset().top);
 })
 $(window).scroll(function(){
     $('.common').each(function(index){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > elemArr[index]) {
                $(this).css({position: 'fixed', top: '85px'});  
                $('.ghost_div'+index).css({display: 'block'});
        } else {
                $(this).css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
                $('.ghost_div'+index).css({display: 'none'});
        }
     });
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a go now. I'm just learning javascript and your code is a great way to see how to do someone more efficiently. I had tried to combine the if statements but couldn't get the syntax right.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work properly. Should this:  if( $(window).scrollTop() > elemArr[index]) {         be something like:        if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('.common')-85 {

Comment: I am glad if it helped you. However can you please tell what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: ok this works  if( $(window).scrollTop() >  elemArr[index]-85)  { for the first menu, but the subsequent menus fix a further 85px higher up the window each? see this super dodgy jfiddle (just copied pasted my code in). As you scroll down the first menu fixes -85 but the rest do not? https://jsfiddle.net/jpolsonb/g9ezqfgc/

Comment: I get it now. It is because when we stored values in elemArr for all elements the first element was not fixed positioned. But later it got fixed and hence the doc height was reduced by the height of first element. Let me see what can be done and I will update the jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks, I worked through your approach and while it introduced quite a few new concepts I'm slowly working through reading up on each. Really appreciate your time

Comment: I am glad it worked for you :) Have updated your code. Please refer this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/g9ezqfgc/6/

Comment: This appears to optimize the *writing* of the code, but not the *execution* of it. You still have a frequently-executed scroll handler, and you still call `$(window).scrollTop()` three times for each time the scroll handler is fired.

Comment: I tweaked it to work correctly by adding the -85 to this part:   if( $(window).scrollTop() >  elemArr[index]-85) @csum I'm going to try and incorporate your suggestion to this function now.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put in

Answer (score 1):

I would say, rather than trying to set the css directly, take advantage of classes.

```css
.fixed_heading_shop,
.fixed_heading_pricetable {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
}
.ghost_div0,
.ghost_div1 {
  display:block;
}
.scroll_trick .fixed_heading_shop,
.scroll_trick .fixed_heading_pricetable {
  position:fixed;
  top:85px;
}
.scroll_trick .ghost_div0,
.scroll_trick .ghost_div1 {
  display:none;
}
```

```js
$(function(){
  var $window = $(window);
  var $body = $('body');
  var top = $('.fixed_heading_shop').offset().top-85;

  $window.scroll(function(){
    if( $window.scrollTop() > top) {
      $body.addClass('scroll_trick');
    } else {
      $body.removeClass('scroll_trick');
    }   
  });
});
```

Comment: I see how this works except that the first element to be fixed intial position is quite far down the page. Could you explain how var top = $('.fixed_heading_shop').offset().top-85; works?

Comment: @JPB This is an error. `top` is only taking into account that particular element when the script should be re-arranged to take things into account individually. Really, the HTML should be rearranged so that each `.ghost_div` shares the same class, each `.fixed_heading` shares the same class, and that each of those pairs has their own wrapping parent. Then, rather than `$body`, `.scroll_trick` would be applied to the particular wrappers whose children met the requirement. I'll see about re-arranging the code, if you're interested.

Comment: No that's ok I've gone with javascript this time but thanks for the different approach, I will come back to this in the future.