# Adding class jQuery else if

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a fixed  header on scroll adding class 'fixed' this works fine. I scroll down and after 50px class 'fixed' is added to my header container and when i scroll back up the 'fixed' class is removed.

Now on my blog pages i'd like the 'fixed' class to always be there, so on page load and even after scrolling up and down i'd like the class 'fixed' to always be added to my header container.

I'm using if else statements in my js but i can't seem to get it working right:

```
//Fixed header on scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 50) {
            $(".header-wrapper").addClass("fixed");
        } else if {
            $('.blog .header-wrapper').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $(".header-wrapper").removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
```

Any ideas how to sort this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes more sense: Set the fixed class on the blog and test if we have a blog or not when adding the scroll event handler

```js
$('.blog .header-wrapper').addClass('fixed');
if ($(".blog").length==0) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {    
    $(".header-wrapper").toggleClass("fixed",$(window).scrollTop()>=50); 
  });
}
```

Do note that the scroll event is triggered every pixel so you may want to [debounce it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415992/debounce-jquery-scroll-events)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use conditions in the `if` clause like so:

```
//Fixed header on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 50) {
        $(".header-wrapper").addClass("fixed");
    } else if($('.blog .header-wraper').length > 0) {
        $('.blog .header-wrapper').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $(".header-wrapper").removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```