# Scroll to the bottom of the page with offset - function running multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some function, which checks if user scrolls to the bottom of the page, if yes, ajax runs and portion of result is added into current page.
This works well, but if i will add negative number to start this function faster, getData() function runs many times, and also all code starts to act strange - you can scroll up by one pixel and this runs again. Below working version without offset, and next with offset which is better for me as function starts earlier, but with loading getData() many times, which is wrong.

I think about some solution with flag - true / false, but i can't figure how do this properly.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    console.log(counter)
    if (counter > sum) {
      return false;
    } else {
      getData(counter);
      counter++;
    }
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight - 300) {
    console.log(counter)
    if (counter > sum) {
      return false;
    } else {
      getData(counter);
      counter++;
      //$(window).unbind('scroll');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Search for "scroll debounce"

Comment: Just to give a little more info, the `scroll` event fires once per pixel scrolled. You need to instead only execute your logic once scrolling has stopped for N milliseconds - this is debouncing, as @mplungjan referred to

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415992/debounce-jquery-scroll-events

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for debouncing tip.
Thanks to this, i was able to fix my code and all works well now.
Below example:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var timer;
  if (timer) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 500) {
      console.log(counter)
      if (counter > sum) {
        return false;
      } else {
        getData(counter);
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }, 200);
});
```